# Can "kitchen" be used as an adjective? eg: Mother painted the kitchen wall

Tags: grammar, word-usage

My little sister was to identify the adjective in this sentence: 
"Mother painted the kitchen wall purple and green".
I understand how *kitchen* can be an adjective as in *kitchen sink*, but I'm not sure if kitchen describes the wall.

Comment: Follow our sister site ELL Q&A ell.stackexchange.com -- have fun!

Comment: Yea, too primitive, man, see?

Comment: What about _purple_ and _green_? They're adjectives, arguably.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. *Kitchen* in both phrases, *kitchen sink* and *kitchen wall* functions the same way: it modifies the noun that follows -- all *adjectives modify nouns*. *Kitchen* is still a noun in both phrases, but because it functions as a [noun that modifies another noun](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/nouns.htm), it's sometimes called a **nominal adjective**. This is common in English. The same website calls them **[denominal adjectives](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/nominal.htm)**. I've never seen that expression before, but it seems reasonable to me (and it's a terminological problem, not a grammatical problem, so I'm happy to change my terminology). A Word document on still another [website](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEgQFjAD&url=http://site.iugaza.edu.ps/sfirwana/files/Nominal-Adjectives.doc&ei=60gtUdr-LIzOkwWVmoDABA&usg=AFQjCNEkSRr4uOWiPWSlTrkRjlLmCVJJeQ&sig2=U7aqisA6RPARXRMwntfIsQ) calls them **adjectival nouns**.

Comment: Adjectives don't have to come into it at all. English is full of **noun compounds**, like _snake bite_ and _pony ride_; we make them up all the time. Anyway, adjectives are just another kind of noun; the Romans never talked about adjectives at all; they just treated them as nouns.

Comment: A "kitchen wall" is not a wall that has the property of being "kitchen" as a "big wall" is a wall with an additional property or modification.Nouns in compound nouns don't modify the way adjectives do. You can't say "a very kitchen wall" like you can "a very big wall". Used this way, nouns actually *identify* things, as nouns do, rather than modify things, as adjectives do. The noun is not being used as an adjective here, it's being used in a way that is unique to nouns.

Comment: @John is of course right: this is a noun–noun compound, not an adjective–noun combo.  These are rather annoying when you’re doing NLP, too. I seem to recall that they’re something that English has always (or long) supported, but that they had become much more common recently (like in the last century or two).

Comment: John is, of course, right, as usual, but he's also right about the fact that terminology is there to help people analyze the grammar & that it doesn't explain anything because the terms are all arbitrary & vary between linguistic paradigms. I read a story in which one character said to another who'd called himself an _atheist_ that he "still believed in God" because he constantly prayed for the card he wanted to come up or the dice to roll his way. As I pointed out in my answer, "kitchen is still a noun in both phrases" but **functions as an adjective**. Praise the Lord Terminology!

Comment: But adjectives have a number of functions. Which one is this?

Comment: @JohnLawler: It simply names **which** wall was painted. The Queen of Hearts painted the _white_ roses red, but "Mother painted the _kitchen_ wall purple and green": these sentences are functionally similar. Whatever function _white_ performs, _kitchen_ performs. The latter is still a noun, "kitchen wall" is still a compound noun,  . In Chinese, adjectives are verbs. If _kitchen_ had no function, it wouldn't need to be there to make the sentence clear (to preclude the need to ask the Q "Which wall?"). Maybe it's a preposed complement? It does "complete the meaning of a given expression".

Comment: Why does it have to be given a different word when it modifies something? Why not just say it modifies or it's a predicate? Those are the two main functions of adjectives.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Yes, it doesn't have to be given a different word. It's a noun that modifies. I talk about function rather than labels, but the OP's kid's teacher put the ADJ label on it & many linguists call it a nominal ADJ or adjectival noun. That's why I told the story about the gambler who believed in God: so many of the high-end users here are stuck on those divine labels. When I write, rewrite, & edit, I want to know what the words are intended to do & whether they function as they should, not what they're called. I got that from you. You know the know the grammar much better than I do.

Answer (score -1):

An adjective is any word in the English language which describes (provides more detail of) an object. Therefore, as the word "kitchen" in the provided example describes which wall mother will be painting, yes, it can be used as an adjective

Comment: So because I can say, "The Vietnam war started during the Eisenhower presidency", it follows that "Vietnam" and "Eisenhower" are also adjectives? That's nuts. In fact, "Vietnam" and "Eisenhower" name very specific things, in this case one specific war and one specific presidency, just as nouns typically do. They aren't adding attributes or properties as adjectives do. The fill a slot an adjective can fill in the sentence, but they do something very different from what an adjective would do in that same slot.